# How to save child node or parent nodes locally in java script

Tags: javascript

I have a tree view with parent node and child node. Now, I am able to add the parent node under sub nodes and child node under sub nodes of child's.

How to save added child nodes and parent nodes locally using java script?

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

onload = function() {

  // create the tree
  var theTree = new wijmo.nav.TreeView('#theTree', {
    itemsSource: getData(),
    displayMemberPath: 'header',
    childItemsPath: 'items'
  });
  theTree.selectedItem = theTree.itemsSource[0];


  // handle buttons
    document.getElementById('btnFirst').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var newItem = { header: document.getElementById('theInput').value },
            node = theTree.selectedNode;
        if (node) {
            theTree.selectedNode = node.addChildNode(0, newItem);
        } else {
                theTree.selectedNode = theTree.addChildNode(0, newItem);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('btnLast').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var newItem = { header: document.getElementById('theInput').value },
            node = theTree.selectedNode;
        if (node) {
        var index = node.nodes ? node.nodes.length : 0;
        theTree.selectedNode = node.addChildNode(index, newItem);

        } else {
        var index = theTree.nodes ? theTree.nodes.length : 0;
        theTree.selectedNode = theTree.addChildNode(index, newItem);
        }
    });
  document.getElementById('btnNoSel').addEventListener('click', function () {
    theTree.selectedNode = null;
    });

  // create some data
  function getData() {
    return [
        { header: 'Building', items: [
        { header: 'Floors' },
        ]
        },  
        ];
  }





}

</script>
```

Comment: search for `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`

Comment: You have to give a little more info. Also share some snippets to help us understand the problem.

Comment: You can store this info in local storage and you can easily manage.

Comment: @HarisBouchlis see my snippet

Answer (score 0):

Save item html:

```
localStorage.setItem("my_saved_element", your_element.innerHTML)
```

Load item html:

```
var my_new_el = document.createElement(localStorage.getItem("my_saved_element"))
```

Comment: `createElement` doesn't take an `innerHTML` value

Comment: Yes... try with: var test = document.createElement("DIV") after test.innerHTML="<p>Test html</p>" and finally... console.log(test.innerHTML)

Comment: Exactly, it needs to be `your_element.innerHTML = localStorage.get…`, not `document.createElement(localStorage.get…)`